# XSLT select check box based on node value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create xslt where I need to check or uncheck check boxes based up on the XML node value. I want check student check box if descr node contains or equal to 'Student' else it should be unchecked. Faculty check box should be checked if decr node contains Faculty or equal to faculty else it should be unchecked.

My XML is

```
<WI>
  <Wi>
    <last_nam>CLARK                         </last_nam>
    <first_nam>HUNTER              </first_nam>
    <wit_flag>1</wit_flag>
    <descr>Faculty      </descr>
  </Wi>
</WI>
<WI>
  <Wi>
    <last_nam>MCMENAMIN                     </last_nam>
    <first_nam>COLLIN              </first_nam>
    <wit_flag>1</wit_flag>
    <descr>Student      </descr>
  </Wi>
</WI>
```

XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                Person
                <br />
                <xsl:value-of select="WI/Wi/lat_nam" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input id="student_flag" name="student_flag" type="checkbox"
                  value="1">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="WI/Wi/descr[contains(text(),Student]">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="'Student'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="'Student'" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </input>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id="Faculty_flag" name="Faculty_flag" type="checkbox"
                  value="1">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="WI/Wi/descr[contains(text(),Faculty]">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="'Faculty'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">0</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="'Faculty'" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </input>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `checked="checked"` rather than `checked="true"`. That's the way boolean attributes in HTML work...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It checked all the check boxes. I want to check the box based on condition like if descr contains Student then only tat check box should be  checked . But it is checking both check boxes even if descr doesnot contain Faculty.

Comment: I modified the line <input id="Faculty_flag" name="Faculty_flag" 
                    <xsl:when test="WI/Wi/descr[contains(text(),'Faculty']">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">1</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="checked">Checked</xsl:attribute>
                    
                    It worked by adding descr text into ' ' and replaced true to checked.